# Getting the scaling right when printing to pdf

Tags: pdf-format, printing, scaling

I have created a report in Mathematica containing Datasets, charts, plots and text. It looks nice on my screen, but everything becomes too large when I print it to PDF. How can I make everything smaller on the printed page?

I also would like to not have the small "In[45]=" and "Out[64]=" etc. on the printed version of my notebook.